# Edit SQL Server Database (INSERT, UPDATE, etc) in ASP.NET (VB)

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

I am currently learning to write ASP.NET website using Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web, and I plan to develop an online shopping website. I have started a New Web Site, added a SQL Server Database (`eCommerce.mdf`) into the WebSite (in VS), created two tables and inserted a row of data using the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE product (product_id char(4) PRIMARY KEY, product_name varchar(50), product_price money, product_stock int);
INSERT INTO product VALUES ('P001', 'Omega Seamaster Planet Ocean 600m', 68000, 7);
CREATE TABLE cart (customer_id char(4), product_id char(4), cart_quantity int);
```

Then I have added a new web form `Product.aspx` into the website and a `GridView` to get data from the `product` table (it shows `SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [product]"` in the source) from my database. It works fine but I want to make a `Button`, namely *Add to cart*, that can do the `INSERT INTO` function to add new rows to the `cart` table. I try to use the following codes:

**Add an `OnClick` event in the `Button` html code**

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Add to cart" OnClick="func1" />
```

**Add the script of `func1` event before `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">`**

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>
<script runat="server">
Sub func1()
    Dim cn As New SqlConnection("I dont know what I should type here!")
    cn.Open()
    Dim cmd = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO cart VALUES ('C001', 'P001', 1);")
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cn.Close()
End Sub
</script>
```

I am not sure about the `ConnectionString` parameter to be passed to `SqlConnection()` because I have tried a lot of examples from the Internet but none of them works for me.

From `connectionStrings` under the `Webconfig` file, other than the `ConnectionString` with name of `DefaultConnection`, it writes `connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\eCommerce.mdf;Integrated Security=True"`.

Moreover, I get the message `An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code` when I click the `Button` in debugging mode if I use `OnClick` event instead of `OnClientClick` event.

So my question is, what should I type as the `ConnectionString` parameter and anything else should I modify to get `func1` work as expected? I also appreciate any other methods.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this.

```
Dim connectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DefaultConnection").ConnectionString
Dim cn As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
cn.Open()
Dim cmd = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO cart VALUES ('C001', 'P001', 1);", cn)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
cn.Close()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it finally works (but I use the `ConnectionString` name (it' actually `eCommerce`) other than `DefaultConnection`). Thank you so much :)